# Fatal error: Call to undefined function filter()

Tags: php, sanitization, sanitize, html-sanitizing

To filter the post variable I use the following function in an include file

```
function filter($post) {
    $post = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($post)));

    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $post = stripslashes($post);

    $post = mysql_real_escape_string($post);

    return $post;
}
```

When I use the following code to filter the post array in the main file

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $post[$key] = filter($value); 
}
```

I receive

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function filter()
```

Any idea?

Comment: It sounds like the file isn't actually included. Have you verified that it is?

Comment: show the code where you are including file with filter function

Comment: @h2ooooooo When I use `<?php $file = fopen ('http://www.site.com/include.php', 'r');?>` in order to include the file i get no error in the error log. is there any other good way to find out if the include file has been included properly.

Comment: Don't `include` local files using a URL, use a filesystem reference.... if you use a url, the code in the include file will be executed and only any echoed output from that code will be what is included

Comment: @SilentPond `fopen` opens a file for reading (it doesn't care whether your content is a video, a PHP file or a text file) - it has *nothing* to do with `include`, `include_once`, `require` or `require_once`. Also these resources should ALWAYS be loaded from a relative/absolute *path* and not an URL. Imagine if your DNS was hacked and you'd suddenly start including files from servers that weren't yours. That'd be a huge problem.

Comment: @Mark Baker & @h2ooooooo but when i include the file like, `<?php include 'include.php'; ?>` it seems that the file is unable to generate sessions & save these to the right directory. Any idea?

Comment: No idea without knowing what the rest of your code looks like

Answer (score 1):

Use `include` or `require` to include a file. You can use get_included_files() function to check for files' inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Include your file before your function is going to be called.

`include_once('yourfilename');
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $post[$key] = filter($value); 
}`

and if you are using class based function file you need to create object for that and after that you can call that function by that object. `include_once('yourfilename');`
$obj = new ClassName;
`foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $post[$key] = $obj->filter($value); 
}`

Comment: Of course the file sad been included that way, thanks.

Comment: I'm encountering session_save_path related problem with my host. It's driving me insane. Configuration in php.ini doesn't take effect on my server. I posted a new question about the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103114/unable-to-generate-save-the-session

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I find to fix this is to simply just add it in again. something like this in your case:

```
function filter($post) {
//do nothing.. for debugging...
}
```

And then you will get a new Error message telling you where the error was located in the first place... e.g "Function Redeclared in file, line number, ...blah blah"